# R percentage according to variable

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

I have a data frame data that I have reshaped with the function dcast. 
Now I would like to include for each value of centre the percentage of people with such bmi3. So for example next to the column A I would like a column Aperc = c(50, 33.33,20)
Here a RE .

How can I do that in R?

```
> library(reshape2)
> data =data.frame("centre"=LETTERS[sample(1:10,size=100,replace=T)], "bmi"=sample(1:3,100, replace=T))
> head(data)
  centre bmi
1      F   2
2      A   1
3      E   3
4      I   1
5      E   1
6      A   1
> d_edu = dcast(data,bmi~centre)
Using bmi as value column: use value.var to override.
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
> d_edu
  bmi A B C D E F G H I J
1   1 5 1 2 6 3 5 3 2 4 0
2   2 3 0 1 2 4 8 2 6 6 3
3   3 2 2 2 3 4 6 3 5 5 2
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
d_edu1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=nrow(d_edu),ncol=(ncol(d_edu)-1)*2+1))
d_edu1[,1] <- d_edu[,1]
d_edu1[,seq(2,ncol(d_edu1), by=2)] <- d_edu[,-1]
d_edu1[,seq(3,ncol(d_edu1), by=2)] <- 100*round(t(t(d_edu[,-1])/colSums(d_edu[,-1])),2)

colnames(d_edu1)[c(1,seq(2,ncol(d_edu1), by=2))] <- colnames(d_edu)

colSums(d_edu1[,seq(3,ncol(d_edu1), by=2)]) ##rounding 
# V3  V5  V7  V9 V11 V13 V15 V17 V19 V21 
# 100 100  99 101 100 101 100 100 100  99
```

You can change the names of the newly generated variables by:

```
 colnames(d_edu1)[c(3,seq(2,ncol(d_edu1), by=2))] <- vector_of_names
```

Comment: this is close to what I want but the the values on the columns V do not sum to 100   '> apply(X=d_edu1,MARGIN=2,FUN=sum)

Comment: I just edited the line d_edu1[,seq(3,ncol(d_edu1), by=2)] <- round((t(t(d_edu[,-1])/colSums(d_edu[,-1])))*100,2)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a for loop to populate the column with this

```
 d_edu[,toString(data[i,1]) ]/sum(d_edu[,toString(data[i,1]) ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have organized your BMI values into rows, `prop.table` with `margin` set to 2 for columns should succeed after a bit of formatting and multiplication (I didn't understand on my first reading that you wanted to do this by separately by column.) I think your example is wrong because the middle percentage value should be 30.

```
 (props_d_edu <- 100*round(prop.table(as.matrix(d_edu[-1]), 2),2) )
 #    --- different than yours since set.seed() was not called ---------
       A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
[1,] 43 12 25 50 45 25 33 62 25 43
[2,] 14 50 42 12 36 50 40 12 44 14
[3,] 43 38 33 38 18 25 27 25 31 43
```

Now to interleave the values by sorting the non-"bmi" column names:

```
d_edu2 <- cbind(d_edu, props_d_edu)
d_edu2 <- d_edu2[ c("bmi", sort(names(d_edu2)[-1])) ]
d_edu2
```

#---------------------------

```
  bmi A Aperc B Bperc C Cperc D Dperc E Eperc F Fperc G Gperc H Hperc I Iperc J Jperc
1   1 3    43 1    12 3    25 4    50 5    45 2    25 5    33 5    62 4    25 3    43
2   2 1    14 4    50 5    42 1    12 4    36 4    50 6    40 1    12 7    44 1    14
3   3 3    43 3    38 4    33 3    38 2    18 2    25 4    27 2    25 5    31 3    43
>
```

Comment: d_edu2[ c("bmi", sort(names(d_edu2)[-1])) ] #gave duplicated columns
d_edu2[c(1,order(names(d_edu2)[-1])+1)] ##should be better

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 d_edu$Aperc <- d_edu$A/sum(d_edu$A)
 d_edu$Bperc <- d_edu$B/sum(d_edu$B)
```

and so on

Then

```
 d_edu = d_edu[c( "bmi", "A",  "Aperc", "B", "Bperc", ..............)]
```